# Limit for outgoing emails for every virtual host

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, postfix

I have virtual hosts on Apache server. I need limited the outgoing emails sent via mail() function(from PHP). Max 100 outgoing emails per day for every host :)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can do something with the `ipt_recent` iptables module, not an ideal solution but should work non the less

Answer (score 2):

It appears that [policyd](http://policyd.sourceforge.net/readme.html) allows sender throttling:

> Sender throttling module allows quota enforcement.  Currently   you
>   may throttle based on amount of mails and total mail size   sent over
>   a given period of time which you define.
>
> Eg: You  can enforce that camis@mweb.co.za does not send more   than 1000 mails or 1gig of mail (whichever limit is hit first)   in
>   say a 5 minute  period.

I have no experience with this.

Answer (score 0):

I have not ever implemented something like this.  But vconceptually you could
1) overload the native mail() function
2) build in logic to you new function which Implements The Limit

See this post on a way that you might be able to overload the mail () function

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17216575/how-to-limit-outbound-smtp-mail-sent-from-php/17382525#17382525

If it works for you please let me know

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault! We prefer whole answers / quoting the most important things from a link as opposed to just posting a link. Please improve your answer by including the vital information directly